# Laravel файлы локализации с помощью базы данных

Tags: laravel, локализация

Пытаюсь создать мульти-язычный сайт с помощью Laravel. Языки английский, русский и испанский. Я создал три папки[ru,en,es] внутри папки lang. Создал файл **Translate.php**. Файл выглядит так:

```
<?php

return [
    'identificator' => 'text',
];
```

Как импортировать все идентификаторы и тексты в базу данных для редактирования, потом после редактирования добавить обратно в файл translate.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем гонять файлы туда обратно если можно использовать локализацию прямо с базы с помощью [этой библиотеки](https://github.com/Waavi/translation#load-translations-from-the-database)

В базе будете хранить данные о языках в таком виде:

```
| id | locale | name    |
-------------------------
| 1  | en     | english |
| 2  | es     | spanish |
```

И саму локализацию вот так:

```
| id | locale | namespace | group       | item            | text                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | en     | *         | validations | missing.name    | Name is missing         |
| 2  | en     | *         | validations | missing.surname | Surname is missing      |
| 3  | en     | *         | validations | min_number      | Number is too small     |
| 4  | es     | *         | validations | missing.name    | Falta nombre            |
| 5  | es     | *         | validations | missing.surname | Falta apellido          |
```

Обращаться всё так же:

```
trans('validations.missing.name');
```

Тем самым вы даете возможность администратору менять локализацию. В библиотеке есть ещё много возможностей, можете ознакомиться на досуге.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, что же я без Вас делал, я помню  Вы еще мне помогли с webmoney для laravel.